# Is there a way to inverse border and background in this situation?

Tags: css, border

I have the following arrow, composed of a rectangle and a triangle (done by using borders). I'm asking this question because I want to be able to fill the triangle with the a gradient, and currently borders do not support gradients. Is there a way to make an inverse of the style I currently have?

```css
.arrow {
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #4e99b8;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #4e99b8;
```

Comment: Just create one in Photoshop.

Comment: I need to be able to scale it and change the color on demand( previewing purposes ). As for the arrow:before, I don't care much about this syntax, I'm using jQuery to set all these properties. Would it be helpful to show the jQuery version of this code?

Comment: what do you mean by inverse? also, i have tried before for awhile to put gradients in borders, but alas, i think it cannot be done at this point.

Comment: By inverse, I meant using the borders to create the negative space instead of creating the triangle shape.

Comment: http://dream-world.us/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/ if you want simple arow like this, here is demo and tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, i suppose i didn't think of creating the arrow by masking a square div. that could totally work.

Comment: You can use `border-image` with a gradient that will then be used as the border.

Comment: Thanks Miljan, this seems as a very cool tutorial, I'll have it in mind, but I need something more portable and easier to work with. It's a bit more than I can chew. Torsten, I tried what you've told me, but unfortunately the border-image renders the gradient on the whole div tag.